# Linkurious console query not showing relationship type(name)

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to use linkurious as a visualization tool, when I enter a cypher query that work in the neo4j GUI and displays the types (relationship name) between nodes, when I run the same query on Linkurious in the console, it will never display the relationship (type).  Here is the query I was running:
match (dbi:DBTable)-[isf:IsSourceFor]->(im:INFAMapping)-[ct:ChangesTarget]->(dbo:DBTable) where dbo.name = "CUST_ACCT_DIM" return *;

Hoping someone is trying this as well.

Comment: Hi,

Our support forum is better suited for this question: https://getsatisfaction.com/linkurious

What is your version of Linkurious?
What information are displayed on the panel when clicking on the relationship?
What happens when you zoom in?

Comment: The version is 12.0 (I'm pretty sure). When clicking on the relationship I get nothing on the relationship. When I zoom in and out I get nothing on the relationship.

Comment: ok can you download the latest version (1.2.3) on the website?

Comment: We are using version 1.2.3, it is not working...

Comment: Also when I export the Jason code from Neo4j the relationships show up but when they do it from Linkurious the relationship(types) are not there.  So something is not working between Linkurious and neo4j, when cypher is run from Linkurious...

Comment: Can you provide me a sample of your database in order to reproduce the bug? Please send it to support@linkurio.us.